# Creating large webgraphs on the command line

Tags: graphviz

Am I going about this this right way?

I have a file called input.txt that has data like this:

```
digraph G {
rankdir=LR
node [shape=box style=filled]
A->B
A->C
A->D
B->D
C->E
E->F
}
```

I then input that into dot.exe which creates the data.dot file:

```
C:\Graphviz\bin\dot.exe < input.txt > data.dot
```

Then I input the dot file back to create my svg file:

```
C:\Graphviz\bin\dot.exe -Tsvg data.dot > data.svg
```

It seems to work for a small amount of data in the input.txt file, but it seems to fail with larger data sets.

I replaced `dot.exe` with `sfdp.exe` but it creates nodes that overlap each other.

Comment: You may create the svg directly from your input file, something like `dot.exe -Tsvg input.txt >data.svg`

Comment: Maybe you want to try other layout engines besides `dot` and `sfdp`. There are also `circo`, `osage`, `neato` and `twopi`.